# How to pair bluetooth HC-05 module to a website

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, hc-05

To start of, i'm REALY new to this so i'm going to need a in depth explanation.

I'm trying to connect my Arduino through Bluetooth to a website. To do this, i'm trying to use the HC-05 bluetooth module. I got the module to work with a app builder and the app bluetooth terminal. I can send text and data to my Arduino.

Now i want to connect it to a website with a pairing button. When clicked, it won't show the device under the pairing tab. I assume this is because it doesn't recognize my module as a pair-able device. Can anyone explain to me how pairing works and if i can get it to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably use the [Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API) on your website, which states (emphasis mine):

> The Web Bluetooth API provides the ability to connect and interact with **Bluetooth Low Energy** peripherals.

Your HC-05 is a Bluetooth Classic device and can not be found using the Web Bluetooth API, which only allows connecting to Bluetooth Low Energy devices. Other adapters will enable you to use BLE with your Arduino; the [HM-10](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/ingo-lohs/bluetooth-hm-10-module-6eb803) is one of them. Another option would be to switch boards entirely and use something like an ESP32 that already comes with BLE.

Comment: thanks! i suspected something like this was the case. I guess i will need to buy another module.